# Querying twice with same operator in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Say I wanted to query for Posts where the content is either like 'good' and either like 'bad', then i'd do this:

```
Post.findAll({
  where:{
        content: {
            [Op.and]: {
                [Op.like]: '%good%',
                [Op.like]: '%bad%'
            }
        }
  }
}
```

But since the object has both properties named [Op.like], the latter one will replace the one above.

So I find no way to be able to query using the same operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it like :

```
[Op.and]: [
    { [Op.like]: '%good%' } ,
    { [Op.like]: '%bad%' }
]
```